# ignore :: Applicative f => f a -> f ()

Tags: haskell, applicative

I need any function with this signature :

```
ignore :: Applicative f => f a -> f ()
```

Can someone point me to the right direction ?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try [hoogling it](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Applicative+f+%3D%3E+f+a+-%3E+f+%28%29&scope=set%3Aincluded-with-ghc)? `void` has exactly that signature...

Comment: Applicatives are functors too.

Comment: ignore a  =  fmap (\x -> ()) a   --- thanks!

Comment: `const` can be nice but I prefer [`-XBlockArguments`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/block_arguments.html?highlight=blockarguments#extension-BlockArguments): `void = fmap \_ -> ()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @Amadan said in the comments, you can easily find answers to this kind of questions by using the [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/) search engine. Nevertheless, here are a few ways you can do this:

1. You can observe that what you need is a mapping to a constant value (`()`). In Haskell, that's `const ()`. All you have to do now is modify this function so that it will affect the value inside an (applicative) functor. And what value makes a function into a function on functors? `fmap`. Put all of this together, and you get solution #1: `fmap $ const ()`.
2. There's a function in the Prelude that takes a functor and replaces its value with another: `(<$) :: Functor f => a -> f b -> f a`. Here, `a` is `()`, so you get solution #2: `() <$`.
3. Use Hoogle, and you get `void` from `Data.Functor` and `Control.Monad`. This function is also useful when you have a monadic action and want to ignore its result by switching it out with `()`.
4. Write it out the long-winded way with a lambda (as you did in the comments): `ignore f = (\_ -> ()) <$> f`, or just `ignore = fmap $ \_ -> ()`

Answer (score 1):

How about turning `f a` into `f b` for an `Applicative f`, do you know of anything that can help you with that?

Something that changes the value "on the inside" while keeping the "outside" intact?

Hint: Applicatives are Functors too.

Comment: Uhh, I don't think `Applicative f => f a -> f b` is inhabited (unless you include bottoms, etc). If it were (call it `foo`), then you'd have `unsafeCoerce = runIdentity . foo . pure`.

Comment: I think @WillNess's point was that `Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` is inhabited.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr yes exactly. I initially wrote `Applicative f => f a -> f b` intending it kind of  informally, but taken literally it made little sense.

Comment: Oh, I guess I should have looked at the edit history.  I though @JosephSible was commenting on the current edit and thought he was reading too much into it.  The comments make sense now.